Help with flashing android os onto an sd card and then onto a phone
I don't even know where to start. I know that I need an SD card reader and my laptop. What size SD card do I need? How do I put the OS onto the SD card? And then how do I put it into the phone? Can someone help me with the right steps?

Have you googled it?  If you have found the OS you want, it will come with instructions.

Android phones don't support booting firmware form sd-card. The only use of an sd-card when installing a firmware is to temporary store the firmware ZIP file there and then boot into recovery ROM and install it from sd-card to the main flash memory. But in general firmware the possible ways to flash a firmware depends on the phone model respectively the phone manufacturer and the used SoC.

Thats exactly what i mean to do, store it as a zip file and boot into recovery ROM and install it from the sd card. I'm not sure what to do to get it onto the sd card and how big of an sd card i need to put it on. The phone is a one plus nord N100

And yes of course, I have googled it. I'm just not getting the answer i'm looking for. I need step by step instructions, also, the phone ir frp locked. not stolen, the person i bought it from didnt tell me it was google locked to their google account and they wont answer me with the info to unlock it.
